# An example of a real closed field in which every 1-type is countable but a type is uncountable

Tags: model-theory

In this question, I consider the language $L_{or} = \{=,<,+,\cdot,1,0\}$ of ordered rings.

My question: Is there an extension of real closed fields $F \subset G$ such that:

- every $a \in G \setminus F$ defines a countable gap (i.e., a cut of countable cofinality on both sides) on $F$ but,
- there exists $\bar{b} \in (G \setminus F)^{< \omega}$ such that $type(\bar{b}/F)$ is uncountably generated ?

My observation:
Let $(x_\alpha \mid \alpha < \omega_1)$ be a decreasing sequence  such that:
\begin{align*}
0 < \epsilon < x_\alpha < n^{-1}
\end{align*}
for each $\alpha < \omega_1$ and each $1\leq n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a minimal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that,

- $\mathbb{F}$ is a real closed field and
- each $x_\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$.

Then, $y_1= \pi - \epsilon$ and $y_2 = \pi + \epsilon$ defines a countable gap on $\mathbb{F}$.
However, $type(y_1,y_2/\mathbb{F})$ is uncountably generated.

In this case, an extension $\mathbb{G}$ must have $\epsilon$, so some single element of $\mathbb{G}$ must define an uncountable gap on $\mathbb{F}$.
So this case is not an answer.

Comment: hi Yushiro. by "countable gap" do you mean a cut of countable cofinality on both sides? also, are you working purely in the field language, or in an o-minimal expansion?

Comment: By “Countable gap”, I mean, as you say, a cut of countable cofinality on both sides. The language I consider is of ordered rings. But it is interesting for me if the language is expanded. I’m sorry about the context of my original question is not clear. I edited it. Thank you for a comment.